# Impossible to access files in /drupal/sites and /drupal/themes after restoring the installation

Tags: media, 9

I restored the files of the Drupal installation, but I'm facing an issue: All the files in /drupal/sites and /drupal/themes are not accessible.

I got only 404 errors when trying to load those files.

I tried changing the permission (777 just temporarily), but it doesn't work. I can see the images with IMCE library, but it seems that Drupal can't access them.

> [image: screenshot]

The front-end is the same.

> [image: screenshot]

The owner of the folders seems to be OK.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check the `/sites/defaul/files` folder to make sure they even still exist?

Comment: Yes, I did, it does exist, it's full of the files that I'd like to display, but I can't access them. When I type the URL of a file directly in the adress bar, I got also a 404 page...

Comment: I think some permission issue or htaccess issue.